# Help. Question about run application on IOS 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

I am using Xcode 4.2 with iOS 5 to develop an application. This application doesn't include any new features provided in iOS 5.1. So, if I submit this app to App Store, can the users download it and run it on their iOS device with iOS 5.1?

Any comments and suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every iOS version is backwards compatible, so yes.

But if you are not including any iOS 5 features, you should target a lower iOS version in Xcode , so users with old devices can run it too. Example: the iPhone 3G can only be updated to run iOS 4.2.